# How to fusion two mongoldb clusters

Tags: database, merge, mongodb-atlas, data-loss

is it possible to move all databases from one mongo cluster to another that contains data? or it should be a new cluster only?

Is is possible to do live migration without putting down the application (I mean , there will be a data writing or reading while doing migration). Is this risky and could involve data loss.
bests,

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to merge more than one cluster in an existing cluster.
However, to avoid losing data, stop the application, change the connection to point the target cluster and cutover.